# Why "no class found error" while using external jar (but I exported external jar too!)

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

In pig, I'm using my udf which is using external jar file routines, and in eclipse I did export that jar file too. But while running pig -x local script1.pig, it gives me error for external jar file routines.

Please help!

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

As asked in comments for my code:

```
script1.pig:

    REGISTER ./csv2arff.jar;

    csvraw = LOAD 'sample' USING PigStorage('\n') as (c);

    arffraws = FOREACH csvraw GENERATE pighw2java.CSV2ARFF(c);
```

pighw2java.CSV2ARFF:

```
public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
        return null;
    try{
            System.out.println(">>> " + input.get(0).toString());
            // 1.1) csv to instances
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.get(0).toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();    **HERE IS ERROR**

                 .....

        }
}
```

Error I got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/converters/CSVLoader
at pighw2java.CSV2ARFF.exec(CSV2ARFF.java:24)
at pighw2java.CSV2ARFF.exec(CSV2ARFF.java:1)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:216)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:305)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:322)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:332)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:284)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:271)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:266)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.converters.CSVLoader
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 14 more
```

Comment: Did you `register` the jar at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Does it tell you a particular class that is missing? Have you looked for it in your jar file with "jar tf /path/to/my.jar"?

Comment: @LorandBendig I registered my own jar (but error is from lib jar classes, that I didn't register as its packaged into my jar)

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus its missing lib jar class (in particular its weka, which I included while creating my project jar file)

Comment: @codemuncher could you please post the exception you get as well as some code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register all of the 3rd party dependencies that are used in your custom UDF. Here:

```
register '/path/to/weka.jar'
```

Comment: I tried that before, it was giving me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error. I think if I have already consider third party jar while creating my jar, why I need that?

Comment: sometime this error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded .. its at first row only, if I register weka.jar too

Comment: @codemuncher If the NoClassDefFoundExecption disappears after registering weka.jar then the problem is solved. That's another question why you get OutOfMemoryError. Probably code that calls to weka should be checked. You may also try to increase the heap size of your cluster nodes, i.e add `set mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx2048m` to the beginning of your script and check whether the heap size of the MR jobs has been increased.

Comment: I tried on grunt menu, without specifying heapsize, and it seems like it fails at DUMP/STORE. my output from udf, I checked with describe is shows {chararray} .. do you have any idea what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you to create a new question for this issue, not just because of better visibility but because this is no more related to this topic